# OS-specific namespace rules in Python

Tags: python, windows, macos, namespaces

The following code works fine on Windows, but raises an UnboundLocalError on Mac:

```
file = open(file_path, newline = '')
reader = file.readlines() 

for line in reader:  
    if "Physical Address" in line: 
        line_ = line 
    if self.ip in line:
        split_line = line_.split()
        break

for word in split_line:     
    if '-' in word:
        dashed_mac_address = word
        break
```

In the second for loop, Python on Windows knows what I'm talking about, but on a Mac 'split_line' and 'dashed_mac_address' are interpreted to be referenced before assignment.

I understand why it's raising that error, but is this correct? Are namespace rules os-specific? I would expect something like that to be standard across any platform.

Comment: This means it's unable to find `self.ip` in the file

Comment: this is just an excerpt, `self.ip` is defined in the first line of the method. defining `split_line` and `dashed_mac_address` as an empty list and string, respectively, before the for loops resolves the error.

Comment: You conditionally assign a value to `line_` and subsequently use `line_` under an unrelated condition when it may not be defined (i.e. is unbound). Similarly, you use `split_line` when maybe nothing has been assigned to it. You're not coding defensively. You have to think through the various branches to make certain your handling all cases.

Comment: I understand you may be asking about differences in the output read from `file_path`, whatever that is. But giving us buggy code doesn't help. The actual problem may be off topic here and need to be asked on Super User -- e.g. if it's simply about parsing output from a command-line program that's different in Windows compared to macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to parse ip/mac address from the terminal output.

If that is the case, the output are different for what is shown in windows cmd prompt and the one shown in Mac's.

Try looking at a sample of what ipaddress output looks like on mac termina and compare it to windows prompt output.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing. I expected there to be differences, so once I finished coding on Windows, I brought it to a Mac. The same method, though, with the same text in the terminal, will not produce an error, it just returns `None`.

Comment: For th problem with self.ip being interpreted as reference before assignment, try looking at the value you have and if value of self.ip is present in it. This situation has occurred because self.ip is not in line and hence split_line is not initialized. But you are trying to access split_line in for loop.